# Heap corruption not detected by Valgrind or Electric Fence. Should I be suspicious? (C++)

Tags: visual-studio, valgrind, memory-corruption, electric-fence

I recently encountered my first [battle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767900/struggling-yet-another-memory-corruption-problem-bad-alloc-c-vs-2008) **(solved)** with heap corruption.  On my linux machine at home the culprit code exits without error using valgrind and electric-fence(with gdb).  Yet on the windows machine in our lab, I consistently get the heap corruption related error message from VS described in my referenced post.

Is it surprising (or at least uncommon) that valgrind and electric fence wouldn't detect such a problem?  Someone else mentioned a possibly similar bug that eluded valgrind in a answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525/of-memory-management-heap-corruption-and-c).  What might be some reasons why this problem wouldn't be detected by these tools?  Is there any reason to doubt that error is in fact heap corruption?

**Update**: As mentioned in the post describing the original problem, I found that the problem was due to having pointers to elements in a std::vector, which became bad.  Replacing the vectors with std::list (to which pointers don't become invalid when adding new elements) fixed the problem. So getting back to my question about why valgrind didn't detect the problem, I ask if there are any recommendations about how to avoid a similar situation in the future, namely a memory problem that isn't detected by valgrind which is one of my favorite tools.  Obviously getting a better understanding of how STL works would be a good idea.  Perhaps I need to be more assertive with assert in my programming, etc.

Comment: Go back to your previous question and try gflags as the answer suggests.  That is absolutely the first thing you should do on Windows when you have heap corruption: gflags /p /full /enable yourprog.exe.  Then leave a comment on that answer describing your results.  If it helps mark it as answered.  Then come back to this question.

Comment: I have been trying to use gflags as the answer suggests but haven't been able to get windbg to find the symbols for my program yet.  Once I do get gflags/windbg working I may have answered my own question so I see your point. Just thought I get some thoughts on this in the meantime while I am continuing to debug.

Comment: gflags has nothing to do with windbg.  You can use gflags with the Visual Studio debugger or any other debugger.

Comment: I tried with VS initially but didn't see any new output in the debug session.  I found an example using glfags with windbg so I was going to try to follow along.  I just ran gflags /p and nothing was listed.  Looks like I had forgot to run it as admin and it wasn't actually enabled after all.  Now I can start in on the debugging with VS!  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is no output with gflags, it just crashs at the point of the overrun instead of later.  To test that you are using gflags correctly write a five line test program and overrun some memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the apparent reason that Valgrind failed to detect your heap corruption is that the corruption did not happen with GCC STL implementation at all (i.e. there was no error to detect).

Unfortunately, Valgrind operates at much lower level than STL, and so many bugs remain undetected. For example:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.resize(0);
v[1] = 42;  // Oops. Out of bounds access, but Valgrind is silent
```

Fortunately, GCC STL has a special debugging mode, designed to catch *many* such problems. Try building your original code with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`. It will likely catch the original problem, and may catch more problems you don't yet know about.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting good results on one machine and bad results on another using the same tool, it'd be a really good idea to run some memory tests on the development machine.  Bootable images for memtest86 can be obtained easily, and certain memory errors could explain your issue neatly.

On the other hand, if you're using different operating systems on each machine it's also possible (maybe even more likely) that a bug exists in the windows versions of whatever crossplatform libraries you're using.

Comment: Well, I am using different operating systems with STL and Boost.

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand what heap corruption is. In particular, memory leaks are *not* heap corruption.

The memory leak reported by Parallel Studio also appears bogus, and more likely to be a bug in Parallel Studio than in your program.

Comment: I'm aware of the difference.  I posted the wrong link, my bad! Have another look please.