# Using iterator and memory location to check instance of object inside list

Tags: c++, list, this

I have a class, like this:

```
class Particle()
{

    void CalcSomething(Super& arg){
        for(unsigned long long index = 0; index < arg.NumberOfParticle(); index ++){                              
            if(this != arg.ParticleMemoryPointer(index)){
                // Do the calculations
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And the following class holds the particles:

```
class Super()
{

    const Particle* const ParticleMemoryPointer(unsigned int index)
    {
        std::list<Particle>::iterator iter = mParticles.begin();
        std::advance(iter, index);
        return &(*iter);
    }

    std::list<Particle> mParticles;
}
```

The idea being, the instance of a particle, which is calling CalcSomething needs to detect when CalcSomething is being called from the same instance of Particle as the one addressed by the index inside the function `CalcSomething`. (Does that make sense? I haven't worded it very well...)

You realize the reason for this is if we are to do a calculation between two particles, we need to make sure they are *different* particles.

Some cout statements show the memory address returned by ParticleMemoryPointer is not the same as the `this` pointer for the case when there is one item in the list. (They should be, with one item, we are doing a calculation with the same particle twice.)

I hope this is understandable.

**Edit** The function inside Super which calls CalcSomething:

```
void Super::UpdateParticles(double time_step)
{
    std::list<Particle>::iterator iter = mParticles.begin();

    for(unsigned long long index = 0; index < mParticles.size(); index ++){
        std::advance(iter, 1);
        iter->CalcSomething(*this);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2** We can't use std::vector. (We know you were thinking it!)

Comment: Be careful - you're passing an `unsigned long long` in to ParticleMemoryPointer as an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the same super object to the CalcSomething?  possibly you've accidently passed a copy of the original super.

Comment: This is a terribly inefficient way to loop over every pairing of particles. `advance` on a `list` iterator. Shudder.

Comment: @PeterWood The bloke in charge doesn't care how long it takes, so long as we fit a hell of a lot of objects into memory.

Comment: std::list has _much_ more per-item overhead than std::vector (which has exactly 0). If you're worried about not being able to allocate enough contiguous storage, use an std::deque

Comment: @Bwmat List is just for testing purposes. We will do some work on making lists of vectors, which I guess is kind of like a deque. One step at a time though.

Answer (score 1):

After you insert an element into a `list`, its pointer will never be invalidated as long as that list and that element exist. See this answer for more info: [Pointers to elements of std::vector and std::list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287801/pointers-to-elements-of-stdvector-and-stdlist)

Just make sure that after you insert into the list, you're not comparing the original, uninserted element with the inserted one - insertion will move or copy the element into the list.

For your intended purpose, I can't help but feel there's an easier method, one that doesn't require `Particle` to know anything about `Super`, and even without checking pointers:

(pseudocode)

```
for particle in particles(start, end - 1):
    for otherParticle in particles(particle + 1, end)
        DoSomething(particle, otherParticle)
```

Comment: @PeterWood, work is usually a word people use to describe something which operates as expected, however that may be. In this case, the expected, or desired, behaviour is that `this != arg.ParticleMemoryPointer(index)`. I hope that clears things up for you.

Comment: @EdwardBird Snarkiness aside (have you folks had your coffee?) pointers will not change once inserted into a list, so yes comparing pointers will work.

Comment: @EdwardBird I apologise, I was forgetting my principles.

Comment: @CongXu No coffee, we are about to go to bed. We simply don't tolerate those who won't use their brains before adding nonsense/spam/unhelpful comments. It's quite clear from the code in the question, albeit not the explanation, how it should `work`. Apologies for any offence caused. Thank you for your input, it is helpful to know the comparison of pointers should work. I will look into it tomorrow.

Comment: @PeterWood I am glad you appreciate my sense of humour.

Comment: @EdwardBird I meant odd really. You seem intent on insulting the people that you need help from. Quite odd.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename Iter, typename Func>
void pair_wise(Iter it, Iter last, Func func) {
    while(it != last) {
        Iter other = it;
        ++other;
        while(other != last) {
            func(*it, *other);
            ++other;
        }
        ++it;
    }
}
```

This will iterate for example with 4 values `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and pair them:

```
(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)
(2, 3), (2, 4)
(3, 4)
```

You can use it with a lambda function in C++11:

```
int main() {
    list<Particle> particles;

    pair_wise(particles.begin(), particles.end(),
              [](Particle& lhs, Particle& rhs) {
                  lhs.doSomething(rhs);
              });                  
}
```

Or pre-C++11, for example, with a function pointer:

```
void calcSomething(Particle& lhs, Particle& rhs) {
    lhs.calcSomething(rhs);
}

int main() {
    list<Particle> particles;

    pair_wise(particles.begin(), particles.end(),
              calcSomething);                  
}
```