# Why is appending std::deque object to itself through std::copy successful if the deque is not large enough?

Tags: c++, copy, language-lawyer, deque, inserter

**The book is right, I just misread a line.**

As the [answer by @uneven_mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57654888/5825294) clearly points out, the following question hinges upon a misreading of mine.

While reading *The C++ Standard Library (2nd edition)* by Josuttis, I got somehow convinced that `coll` at page 457 is declared as a `std::deque` (on the contrary, it is declared as `std::list`!), hence I asked this question.

I hope it can serve as food for thought for the readers.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

At page 456 of "The C++ Standard Library (2nd edition)", Josuttis remarks that before you call

```
copy(coll.begin(), coll.end(), back_inserter(coll));
```

on a `coll` of class `std::vector`, you must ensure that `coll` has enough space (in this case, that it has a `capacity` at least twice its `size`), otherwise

> the algorithm invalidates the passed source iterators while running.

Contrariwise, at page 458, he doesn't say anything similar for the case of

```
copy(coll.begin(), coll.end(), front_inserter(coll));
```

as applied to a `coll` of class `std::deque`, even though, at page 286, the following is specified about the `std::deque` container:

> [...] when elements are inserted at the front or the back. In this
>   case, references and pointers to elements stay valid, but iterators
>   don’t.

hence my doubt. (Yes, I know `std::deque` doesn't even offer a `reserve`-like member function.)

As long as I have understood [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1659688/5825294), my understanding is that the `front_inserter(coll)` iterator **can** cause a reallocation of the array of pointers (which is a legal way of implementing `std::deque`), and **cannot** cause reallocation of the arrays in which the actual elements of `coll` are stored, thus leaving references/pointers **to the elements** valid, while invalidating the `iterator`s, whose correct behavior (I'm thinking of how `operator++` could be implmented) relies on both the array of pointers and the pointed-to arrays.

If this is true, then I guess that the parameter corresponding to [`copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)'s argument `coll.begin()` gets invalidated at the moment the assignment to it causes a reallocation of the array of pointers.

Comment: I believe `copy(coll.begin(), coll.end(), front_inserter(coll));` exhibits undefined behavior. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: Well, based on the code I'm running it *seems to work*, indeed. But the book presents that chunk of code as a  working example.

Comment: The book is wrong. Don't write code like that.

Comment: Even the `vector` case is technically disallowed: inserting the first element invalidates the past-the-end iterator.

Comment: Indeed, as I alluded in the question, the book warns _that you must not forget to reserve enough space before calling `copy()`_.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, what puzzles me is that the book does not simply express something which looks wrong to (and to you, I understand), but it contraddicts itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 455/456 of the book introduces `std::back_inserter`, while page 457/458 introduces `std::front_insert`. There is a short explanation in each case, including a list of applicable container. Each section has a code snippet as example, with only *one* of the applicable containers chosen to exemplify the usage.

For `std::back_inserter`, as container `std::vector` is chosen and a comment in the code snippets mentions, why it is necessary to first reserve enough space in the vector.

For `std::front_inserter` the author chose `std::list`, not `std::deque`. `std::list` does not invalidate references or iterators on insert, therefore

```
copy(coll.begin(), coll.end(), front_inserter(coll));
```

is fine, see [[list.modifiers]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/list#modifiers-1) of the current C++ draft.

There is therefore in both cases no error in the author's code. I suppose he did never intend to fully explain the dangers of copying into a container itself, but simply chose these cases, because it allowed him to write shorter complete usage examples.

I think for the case where `coll` is a `std::deque` this is clearly undefined behavior. `std::front_inserter` inserts elements by calls to `push_front` (see [[front.insert.iter.ops]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/front.insert.iterator#front.insert.iter.ops-2)), which invalidates all iterators (see [[deque.modifiers]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/deque#modifiers-1)):

At the same time `std::copy`s behavior is [[alg.copy]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.copy#3):

> *Effects*: Copies elements in the range [first, last) into the range
>   [result, result + N) starting from first and proceeding to last. For
>   each non-negative integer n <
>   N, performs *(result + n) = *(first + n).

After the first insert, `first` is invalidated and undefined behavior will be caused.

Comment: I'd rather downvote my question, since now I realized (thank you) that `coll` is declared as `std::list`, not as `std::deque`. What a terrible misreading of mine!